# PostgreSQL Calculating distance in meters between floats coordinates, and geom

Tags: php, postgresql, postgis

I have to queries, one tries to calculate the distance between floats coordinates (x1,y1,x2,y2), and the other tries to calculate the distance between a geom and an float coordinate, both should return distance in meters.

I'm using the following query for the 2 floats:

```
ST_Distance_Sphere(st_setsrid(st_makepoint(longitude, latitude),4326), st_setsrid(st_makepoint(?,?),4326)) AS distance
```

And The querty for geom and float is:

```
ST_Distance_Sphere(geom, st_setsrid(st_makepoint(?,?),4326)) AS distance
```

I can't to fully understand the SRID concept, and I'm having the feeling that my numbers are incorrects because of it.

Can someone help to output a distance in meters?

Thanks,
Itay.

Comment: are you sur that you have to use ST_Distance_sphere with SRID, i'm don't use postgis but it look with ST_Distance_sphere you have to use point, not SRID

Comment: @MacBooc Actully I have no idea, by the lack of my experience with distances and SRID I Would like to hear from more experienced developers